# How to list the actual cronjobs?

Tags: cron

If I (e.g.: under Fedora) edit the crontab file with vim, then I restart crond:

```
/etc/init.d/crond restart
```

then the actual crontab file: "/etc/crontab" is the same as the actual cronjobs in reality. Ok!
But:

Q: How could I list the real-actual cronjobs, if the "/etc/crontab" file gets modified, but the crond not reloaded? Then the real-actual cronjobs aren't the same as the "/etc/crontab" file.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the implementations of cron that I know of re-read `/etc/crontab` every minute, i.e. as often as they execute jobs. So the “real-actual” cron jobs are the ones in the crontab file.

There are (or were) a few buggy implementations of cron that check for jobs to execute first and only then check the crontabs. This causes one minute's delay between setting the jobs and running them. I don't think any of the current cron implementations on Linux (there are several) are affected.